# Go panic interface conversion with a compatible interface

Tags: go, go-ethereum

I'm facing an unsupportable problem for hours, I have to decode data from an Ethereum smart contract call (but it's not the topic because this part work) but I recover theses data into an `interface{}`.

And when I want to cast this empty interface to a struct that I can use, I got this message : `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is struct { SrcToken common.Address "json:\"srcToken\""; DstToken common.Address "json:\"dstToken\""; SrcReceiver common.Address "json:\"srcReceiver\""; DstReceiver common.Address "json:\"dstReceiver\""; Amount *big.Int "json:\"amount\""; MinReturnAmount *big.Int "json:\"minReturnAmount\""; Flags *big.Int "json:\"flags\""; Permit []uint8 "json:\"permit\"" }, not oneinch.OneInchSwapDataDesc`

The struct is :

```golang
type OneInchSwapDataDesc struct {
    SrcToken        common.Address
    DstToken        common.Address
    SrcReceiver     common.Address
    DstReceiver     common.Address
    Amount          *big.Int
    MinReturnAmount *big.Int
    Flags           *big.Int
    Permit          []uint8
}
```

When I look for the type and the data value I got :

```golang
fmt.Println("Type: ", reflect.TypeOf(data))
fmt.Printf("Data: %+v\n", data)

// Logs:
// Type:  struct { SrcToken common.Address "json:\"srcToken\""; DstToken common.Address "json:\"dstToken\""; SrcReceiver common.Address "json:\"srcReceiver\""; DstReceiver common.Address "json:\"dstReceiver\""; Amount *big.Int "json:\"amount\""; MinReturnAmount *big.Int "json:\"minReturnAmount\""; Flags *big.Int "json:\"flags\""; Permit []uint8 "json:\"permit\"" }
// Data: {SrcToken:0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174 DstToken:0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F SrcReceiver:0x11431a89893025D2a48dCA4EddC396f8C8117187 DstReceiver:0x2C2d6E5E16FE924cE31784cdAd27C01D1BC62873 Amount:+10000000 MinReturnAmount:+9949450 Flags:+4 Permit:[]}
```

I think this problem come from those "json" that comes out from the TypeOf but I don;t find any tricks to clear it (in fact, I'm not really sure if the problem really come from that).

If someone have an idea, you'll save my brain from burning in hell.
Thanks.

Comment: A struct is not an interface, and the fields that a struct has have no bearing on interfaces, which have only methods.

Comment: I think you're wrong an empty interface is a kind of any type, so it can be has more than just methods and can be casted to struct or scalar

Comment: I'm not wrong. `interface{}` can "point" to anything but that doesn't let you "cast" the thing it points to to some other thing, that has nothing to do with interfaces. You get a struct or other concrete type out of an interface with a type assertion, and that works by testing the underlying concrete type, not by a form of "casting".

Comment: @LaGregance, type-assertion is not casting. Type assertion will work if the type of the object in the interface is assignable to the type asserted. For a definition of "assignability", see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications, it will help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface has a value of type `struct { SrcToken ...}`. It is an unnamed type. Type assertion will only work if the types are identical, or if the asserted type is an interface and the underlying interface type implements that interface. The type you are trying to convert to is not an interface, but a struct. So you can do this:

```
value:=data.(struct { 
SrcToken common.Address `json:"srcToken"`
 DstToken common.Address `json:"dstToken"`
 SrcReceiver common.Address `json:"srcReceiver"`
 DstReceiver common.Address `json:"dstReceiver"`
 Amount *big.Int `json:"amount"`
 MinReturnAmount *big.Int `json:"minReturnAmount"`
 Flags *big.Int `json:"flags"`
 Permit []uint8 `json:"permit"` })
```

Once you have this, you can convert `value` to the type you want using:

```
targetValue:=oneinch.OneInchSwapDataDesc(value)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it's work thanks ! But what is supposed to mean a type like that : common.Address `json:"srcToken"` ?

Comment: It is a struct type with json tags.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about Tags, it can be useful